# How can I remove a self signed root certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-platform, wordpress, openssl

I'm using bitnami wordpress on GCP. I'm new to server networking.

There is this root signed certificate that I can't changed. I have not installed any SSL on the server. I've searched through the bitnami wordpress documentation but can't find any mention about this.

I've tried to delete the certificates I found on the server in the directory and generate a temp SSL but still it shows insecure connection **example.com** [It is literally **example.com**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3YOL.png)

Is this the default self signed certificate for apache? How can I remove it and install the SSL for actual domain name?

[It is literally **example.com**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3YOL.png)

Comment: Bitnami seems to provide a [dummy certificate](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/how-to/troubleshoot-ssl-issues/) that you'll have to replace with your own e.g. [letsencrypt](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/) key and certs.

Comment: Thanks @digijay Appreciate the input. I have created a new thread which provides more context to the question. https://serverfault.com/questions/1068661/is-downtime-unavoidable-during-migration. I will delete this post

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a "real" SSL certificate you have two options here.

1. [Self managed certificate](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs) - you can get one from LetsEncrypt for example, it free of charge but you have to renew it every year. Hare you'll find instructions specific for installing a LetsEncrypt cert on [Nginx running on top of Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04).
2. [Google's managed SSL certificate](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs) but you'd have to set up a [HTTPS external load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/load-balancer-howto) in front of your Wordpress site. You can read more about [Load balancing cost](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing#lb) in the documentation. SSL certificates are also free of charge.

You may also find the [GCP's SSL certificate overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates) docs helpful and if you have any trouble with setting up a SSL certificate you may check out this [SSL troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting) documentation.

Comment: Hello @FlyingPenguin and welcome to ServerFault! Please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 
That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention. Enjoy your stay!