# From AWS to GCP - Is downtime unavoidable during migration?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, openssl, migration

I'm trying to migrate a bitnami wordpress from AWS to GCP. I would like to avoid downtime during the migration. As a new learner, I am not sure how to best handle this.

I have encountered some roadblocks. Typically on **Load Balancer** and **SSL**

1. I would like to use a load balancer on GCP. I prefer Google's managed certificate but the domain's IP is tied to AWS's server. I have to release them from AWS first and that will be quite a bit of downtime waiting for GCP to validate and provision.
2. If I were to use own certificate on GCP's load balancer just for the migration purpose to avoid downtime, will there be downtime if I switch back to Google's managed SSL?
3. The bitnami wordpress VM's on GCP has a dummy self-signed root certificate pointing to **example.com** [CN=example.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TgyY.png) that I can't remove, more likely I don't know how to. How can I remove or replace that with actual domain name?
4. I am unable to generate a letsencrypt on GCP's server because the domain is still tied to AWS's server. Again, I have to release them first before I can use it on GCP and that will result in downtime.
5. If I use SSL on loadbalancer, do I still need to install SSL on server? Will the virtual host 443 work without SSL installed on the server?
6. Is it possible to create the loadbalancer without providing a SSL for frontend? I don't see an option to do so on GCP's console.

I understand my questions are probably very elementary. I really appreciate any directions at this point.

Thanks